# Blender 3.3.1 vs 3.4.1 API Properties not available to user anymore?

Tags: python, properties, custom-properties

Why are custom object properties defined by API no longer available in the Objects Custom Properties menu? Is there any way to bring them back?

Video demo:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6ci7.jpg

Simple code used in demo to show the change:

````py
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty

class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Custom property test"""
    bl_idname = "object.custom_prop_test"
    bl_label = "Custom prop test"

    def execute(self, context):
        context.selected_objects[0].test = 10
        return {"FINISHED"}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ModalOperator.bl_idname, \
    text=ModalOperator.bl_label)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)
    bpy.types.Object.test = bpy.props.IntProperty(name='test prop', default=0 )

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)
    del bpy.types.Object.x_offset


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: i cannot see any property in both versions if i run your code. Maybe you wanna try this to assign (make sure) a value exists of that property? bpy.context.active_object["test prop"] = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `Developer Extras` in Preferences > Interface > Diplay

> UI: only show API defined custom properties when Developer Extras is
> on.
>
> These are intended to behave just like any other builting property, so
> no to always show them in the Custom Properties panels for regular
> users.

[[Link]](https://developer.blender.org/rBSdc00d66c897fb30b2742812f2669fa79a941839e)

Comment: Do you know if IntProperty's options LIBRARY_EDITABLE should make it visible even without developer extras on? I've tried this but it still didn't show on my end if I recall correctly. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/property_flag_items.html#rna-enum-property-flag-items